# Share circuits between different simulators

Tags: simulation

How do we share circuits between different simulators ?

Say, we have 3 simulation tools ; Proteus, multisim, and LTSpice ( or anything else). How do we share the circuits made in one of the simulation tools ?

Say I have a circuit in Proteus. Now I want to work with the same circuit in Multisim without having to build it again. Is it possible ? If so how ?

Thank you

Comment: It may work or it may not. There is no general rule except to translate the circuit into spice annotation i.e. an ascii file

Comment: How do I do translate it ? Some special software ? And how do I import this translated file then ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spice originally started with ascii type files (or text type files) describing connections between components - these are still the bottom line file used by all spice simulators I believe. Here's an example: -

[image]

And is described by the following text: -

```
Example_1 EXMPL01.CIR
Vs   1   0   DC   20.0V ; note the node placements
Ra   1   2   5.0k
Rb   2   0   4.0k
Rc   3   0   1.0k
Is   3   2   DC   2.0mA ; note the node placements
.END
```

As can be seen, Vs is described on the 1st main line as connected between node 1 and node 2, having a DC value and that value is 20V. Note the node numbers on the schematic and note that all 5 components in the circuit have a line with node connections. Node zero is the default for 0V/Earth.

Like I said in my comment, any circuit/schematic front-end still converts the circuit you draw to a file like this meaning, you can export the ascii/text file and more than likely, import it into another spice software package. However, it probably won't back-engineer some kind of schematic for your convenience. This would be asking too much I expect!!

[Here](http://www.uta.edu/ee/hw/pspice/pspice01.htm) is where I got the example from and it looks nice and easy for a learning tutorial. It should get you started on the nuts and bolts.

BTW, when I first started using spice (mid 90s) this is all realistically anyone got when buying software - the ability to "code" the nodes with text and usually a large file of compoent definitions.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is what we call netlist. And in fact, i do have an option to import netlist in a simulator. And yes, its possible to build the circuit using the net list. I found this : http://www.ni.com/white-paper/11743/en/#toc3

Comment: @Plutoniumsmuggler yeah it's called a netlist. I don't know how I managed to avoid using that term!!!